# Getting value cannot be null asp.net mvc IF i include the session id to my query

Tags: asp.net

Good day i have problem pertaining to my project. When i use my session and I include it to my mysql script in where i got the error of (Getting value cannot be null), then if I used static employee id to my where clause then there is no problem.

I have here the illustration of my cshtml
[image: cshtml]

and this is my  Controller

```
using ro4apaymast.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ro4apaymast.Controllers
{
    public class ScheduleConController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ScheduleCon/

        public ActionResult schedule()
        {

            if (Session["Idno"] == null)
            {

                return Redirect("~/Home/Login");
            }
            else
            {
                List<User> sheet = new List<User>();


            string configuration = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(configuration))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string sqluser = "select fname,lname,mname from employees where empid = '" + Session["IDno"] + "' ";
                    MySqlCommand cmduser = new MySqlCommand(sqluser, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader druser = cmduser.ExecuteReader();

                    while (druser.Read())
                    {
                        sheet.Add(new User()
                        {
                            fname1 = druser["fname"].ToString(),
                            lname = druser["lname"].ToString(),
                            mname = druser["mname"].ToString()

                        });
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }  


                // dropdown
                List<SelectListItem> item8 = new List<SelectListItem>();
                List<SelectListItem> item9 = new List<SelectListItem>();

                //logs








                String Configuration = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Configuration);

                String query = @"SELECT effectiveDate,


            CASE

                WHEN  min(log) = max(log) and description = description and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT(description,' ',min(log))
                WHEN min(log) != max(log) and description = description and timestatus='OK'
                THEN concat(description ,' ', min(log),' ',max(log))
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
                WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='1' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN log
                WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'
                THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
                WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='1'
                THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='1' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='1' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
                WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday'
                THEN 'Saturday'
                WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday'
                THEN 'Sunday'
                WHEN note='HOLIDAY' and counter='1' and timestatus='OK' THEN NULL
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='1' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN note
                WHEN note is NULL THEN 'ABSENT'
                WHEN note is NULL and log = log
                THEN 'ABSENT'

              END am1,


              MAX(CASE
                 WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and description = description and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'
                THEN concat(description,' ',log)
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
                WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='2' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN log
                WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'
                THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
                WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='2'
                THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='2' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='2' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
                WHEN note='HOLIDAY' and counter='2' and timestatus='OK' THEN NULL
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='2' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN note

              END) am2,


              MAX(CASE
                 WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and description = description and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'
                THEN LEFT(description,length(description) -2)
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
                WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='3' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN log
                WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'
                THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
                WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='3'
                THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='3' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='3' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
                 WHEN note='HOLIDAY' and counter='3' and timestatus='OK' THEN NULL
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='3' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN note
              END) am3,


              MAX(CASE

                 WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and description = description and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'
                THEN LEFT(description,length(description) -1)
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'  then CONCAT('Saturday',' ',log)
                WHEN DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and note = 'REGULAR LOGGED'  and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'  then CONCAT('Sunday',' ',log)
                WHEN note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter ='4' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN log
                WHEN note = 'VACATION LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'
                THEN 'VACATION LEAVE'
                WHEN note = 'SICK LEAVE' and timestatus='OK' and counter ='4'
                THEN 'SICK LEAVE'
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='4' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Sunday',' ',note)
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='4' and DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN CONCAT('Saturday',' ',note)
                WHEN note='HOLIDAY' and counter='4' and timestatus='OK' THEN NULL
                WHEN note is not null and counter ='4' and timestatus='OK'
                THEN note

              END) am4,



                CASE
                  WHEN log=log and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) != 'Saturday' and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) != 'Sunday' and description = description and timestatus='OK'
                  THEN '1'
                END holiday,
                    CASE
                  WHEN log=log and NOT DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' AND NOT DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK' and note != ''
                  THEN '1'
                END LOGS,
                CASE
                  WHEN log=log and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Saturday' and timestatus='OK'
                  THEN '1'
                END SaturdayFil,


                CASE
                  WHEN log=log and  DAYNAME(effectiveDate) = 'Sunday' and timestatus='OK'
                  THEN '1'
                END SundayFil,

               CASE
                  WHEN note is NULL and effectiveDate = CURDATE()
                  THEN '1'
                END validationAbsent,

                DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '%W') as DAY_OF_WEEK

                FROM schedules
                LEFT JOIN timesheet ON schedules.effectiveDate = timesheet.date and schedules.empid = timesheet.empid
                LEFT JOIN holidays ON schedules.effectiveDate = holidays.date
                WHERE effectiveDate <= CURDATE()
                AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
                AND MONTH(effectiveDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND schedules.empid = '" + Session["IDno"] + "' GROUP BY effectiveDate";

                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var sheetModel = new User();
                    sheetModel.in_log_am = dr["am1"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.out_log_am = dr["am2"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.in_log_pm = dr["am3"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.out_log_pm = dr["am4"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.day_today = dr["DAY_OF_WEEK"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.dated = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["effectiveDate"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    sheetModel.am1_filter = dr["SaturdayFil"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.am2_filter = dr["SundayFil"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.pm1_filter = dr["LOGS"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.pm2_filter = dr["validationAbsent"].ToString();
                    sheetModel.holiday_filter = dr["holiday"].ToString();
                    sheet.Add(sheetModel);
                }
                connection.Close();










                String sql6 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y') as YEAR FROM timesheet WHERE empid= '" + Session["IDno"] + "' GROUP BY YEAR";
                MySqlCommand cmd6 = new MySqlCommand(sql6, connection);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr6 = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr6.Read())
                {
                    item8.Add(new SelectListItem()
                    {

                        Text = dr6["YEAR"].ToString(),
                        Value = dr6["YEAR"].ToString()

                    });
                }
                ViewData["list"] = item8;

                connection.Close();

                item9.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "MONTH",
                    Value = "1",
                });

                item9.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "YEAR",
                    Value = "2",
                });

                ViewData["list2"] = item9;
                // end this is for dropdown year and month value

                String sql = @"SELECT

CASE WHEN counter IN('1','2','3','4') THEN SUM(counter = 1 AND note ='VACATION LEAVE') END as VL,
CASE WHEN counter IN('1','2','3','4') THEN SUM(counter = 1 AND note ='SICK LEAVE') END as SL,
CASE WHEN counter IN('1','2','3','4') THEN SUM(counter = 1 AND note ='REGULAR LOGGED') END as daysworked,
CASE WHEN description = description THEN COUNT(description) END as Count_holiday

FROM timesheet left join employees on timesheet.empid = employees.empid
LEFT JOIN holidays on timesheet.date = holidays.date

where employees.empid = '" + Session["IDno"] + "' AND YEAR(timesheet.date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(timesheet.date) = MONTH(CURDATE())";


                MySqlCommand cmd_sum = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
                MySqlDataAdapter dr_sum = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd_sum);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dr_sum.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow x in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ViewData["daysworked"] = x["daysworked"].ToString();
                    ViewData["sl"] = x["SL"].ToString();
                    ViewData["vl"] = x["VL"].ToString();
                    ViewData["Count_holiday"] = x["Count_holiday"].ToString();
                }



                return View(sheet);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

######## AND THE ERROR

[image: Error!!]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of **fetch_date.pm1_filter** is not null before checking it's count